# sed plus sign doesn't work

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace `/./` or `/././` or `/./././` to `/` only in bash script. I've managed to create regex for sed but it doesn't work.

```
variable="something/./././"
variable=$(echo $variable | sed "s/\/(\.\/)+/\//g")
echo $variable # this should output "something/"
```

When I tried to replace only `/./` substring it worked with regex in sed `\/\.\/`. Does sed regex requires more flags to use multiplication of substring with `+` or `*`?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use `-r` option to make `sed` to use extended regular expression:

```
$ variable="something/./././"
$ echo $variable | sed -r "s/\/(\.\/)+/\//g"
something/
```

Comment: FYI - extended regular expressions are enabled via '-E' on OSX & BSD. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction (rtfm for 'extended')!

Answer (score 4):

Two things to make it simple:

```
$ variable="something/./././"
$ sed -r 's#(\./){1,}##' <<< "$variable"
something/
```

- Use `{1,}` to indicate one or more patterns. You won't need `g` with this.
- Use different delimiterers `#` in above case to make it readable
- `+` is ERE so you need to enable `-E` or `-r` option to use it

Answer (score 4):

Any sed:

```
sed 's|/\(\./\)\{1,\}|/|g'
```

But a `+` or `\{1,\}` would not even be required in this case, a `*` would do nicely, so

```
sed 's|/\(\./\)*|/|g'
```

should suffice

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with bash's built-in parameter substitution. This doesn't require `sed`, which doesn't accept `-r` on a Mac under OS X:

```
variable="something/./././"
a=${variable/\/*/}/                   # Remove slash and everything after it, then re-apply slash afterwards
echo $a
something/
```

See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for explanation and other examples.

Comment: Yep, for `mac` we need to use `-E`.

Comment: @jaypal: Or install a proper GNU sed ;-)

Comment: The sed included with MacOS 11.6 interprets -r the same as -E, for compatibility with GNU sed. This is described in the man page, dated March 27, 2017.