# Difference between [0-9]* and [0-9]+ in sed

Tags: regex, sed

To my understanding, * matches zero or more and + matches one or more. 
So when I did this on macOS:

```
echo "1" |  sed 's/[0-9]*//g'
```

The number was deleted.

But if I do this:

```
echo "1" |  sed 's/[0-9]+//g'
```

The number will still be there.

But shouldn't [0-9]+ matches "1" as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed plus sign doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099623/sed-plus-sign-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (probably) about whether the `sed` command is running in POSIX (strict) mode or whether GNU extensions are enabled.

In POSIX mode, a `+` in a `sed` regex is not a meta-character.

In GNU extension mode, a `+` means "one or more repetitions". GNU extensions are enabled using the `-E` option.

For more information about sed regexes:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: This is not so much GNU vs. non-GNU (MacOS has BSD sed), but rather about BRE (Basic Regular Expressions vs. ERE (Extended Regular Expressions). Both are described in the POSIX specification. The -E option interprets the expression as ERE.

Answer (score 1):

`+` in sed is considered part of the extended-regular expressions, and so, by default, `+` is not recognized as a special character. Use the `-E` flag to enable extended regular expressions like so:

```
echo "1" |  sed -E 's/[0-9]+//g'
```