# Finding it difficult to extract digits from string using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to extract the version information a string using sed as follows

```
echo "A10.1.1-Vers8" | sed -n "s/^A\([0-9]+\)\.\([0-9]\)\.[0-9]+-.*/\1/p"
```

I want to extract '10' after 'A'. But the above expression doesn't give the expected information. Could some one please give some explanation on why this statement doesn't work ?

I tried the above command and changed options os sed but nothing works. I think this is some syntax error

```
echo "A10.1.1-Vers10" | sed -n "s/^X\([0-9]+\)\.\([0-9]\)\.[0-9]+-.*/\1/p"
```

Expected result is '10'
Actually result is None

Comment: Why do you think `X` will match `A`?

Comment: sorry that was a typo .. even 'A' also doesn't work

Comment: Sure, because of `+` in a BRE POSIX pattern that is treated as a literal `+` char. Use `sed -n "s/^A\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p" <<< "A10.1.1-Vers10"` or `sed -n -E "s/^A([0-9]+).*/\1/p" <<< "A10.1.1-Vers10"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed plus sign doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099623/sed-plus-sign-doesnt-work)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes this works. Is there any tool with which I can debug sed command ?

Comment: I know no tool for `sed` command debugging :( Only [`awk`](https://awk.js.org/). Just googled [a `sed` cheatsheet](http://anaturb.net/sed.htm). A generic shell [script check](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Just wondering: isn't `grep` more suitable for your task?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "A10.1.1-Vers8" | sed -r 's/^A([[:digit:]]+)\.(.*)$/\1/g'
10
```

Search for string starting with A (`^A`), followed by multiple digits (I am using [POSIX character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) `[[:digit:]]+`) which is captured in a group `()`, followed by a literal dot `\.`, followed by everything else `(.*)$`.

Finally, replace the whole thing with the Captured Group content `\1`.

In GNU sed, `-r` adds some syntactic sugar, in the man page, it is called as `--regexp-extended`

Comment: Is that `/g` option needed?

Comment: g doesn't appear needed.  Could also simply remove the A and everything after the period.  `sed 's/A//;s/\..*//'`

Comment: Is there any way we can get a verbose output or a debug for sed - so that I can debug how sed treat the pattern and where things go wrong !

Answer (score 1):

GNU `grep` is an alternative to `sed`:

```
$ echo "A10.1.1-Vers10" | grep -oP '(?<=^A)[0-9]+'
10
```

The `-o` option tells `grep` to print only the matched characters.

The `-P` option tells `grep` to match Perl regular expressions, which enables the `(?<=` lookbehind zero-length assertion.

The lookbehind assertion `(?<=^A)` ensures there is an `A` at the beginning of the line, but doesn't include it as part of the match for output.

If you need to match more of the version string, you can use a lookforward assertion:

```
$ echo "A10.1.1-Vers10" | grep -oP '(?<=^A)[0-9]+(?=\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-.*)'
10
```